# What is difference between app.apk and app-release.apk

Tags: flutter

After running flutter clean and flutter build apk --release
I have two apks in build/app/outputs/flutter-apk. app.apk and app-release.apk.
What are their differences as I see both have the exact same size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think nothing.
app.apk can be equal to app-release if your last build was --release, otherwise app-debug if your last build was --debug.